# How to edit an eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-plugin

An eclipse plugin called `JDTCommentsV2_1.0.9` does the following in eclipse:

[image: http://i90.photobucket.com/albums/k274/alaa_137/eclipse_zps8fbc1a0b.png]

I'm trying to add/edit some comments inside. e.g. add `Run TestComment` or just change one of the comments' name.

I have the `.jar` file and here's how it looks inside:

[image]

Question is which files should i edit and how.

Thank you

**edit:**
After following @greg449 and @Robin Green's instructions, I exported the `jar` file to eclipse, and edited the `plugins.xml` file. But if i export the files now as a jar, it doesn't work (nothing is changed in the menu). Finally i tried what @Robin Green said (Run -> Run As -> eclipse application) but there is no `eclipse application` under `Run As`. I got only `Java Applet` and `Java Application`. I'm wondering why. Might it be because i'm using ADT?

**edit2:**
I downloaded another version of eclipse (not ADT) and here i do have the Run As eclipse application bar". Can't i add it to ADT ?

**edit3:**
The picked answer works for eclipse JDT and not eclipse ADT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a jar containing an existing Eclipse plugin so in your Eclipse you do `File > Import` and choose `General > Existing Projects into Workspace` and select the jar as the source.

Once you have the plugin project installed in your workspace you are going to have to work out how the plugin works by looking at the source and the `plugin.xml`.

Once you have modified the plugin use `Export > Plug-in Development > Deployable plug-ins and fragments` to build a new plugin jar.

Comment: after opening the `.jar` in eclipse i saw a lot of other `.jar` files (such as `resources.jar` , `rt.jar` , etc.) and a directory called `src`. Inside it there are some Packages, but i can't find the `plugin.xml`

Comment: The listing you posted shows the plugin.xml - import the jar that contains that.

Comment: that's what i did. I see the `plugin.xml` if i extract the `jar` using winrar, but i don't see it after exporting in eclipse.

Comment: @greg449 I did find it. Now i'm having other problems... I'll post again later. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AlaaM. You must use the plug-in export **not** jar export - see edited answer.

Comment: OK i don't have that option (`plugin development...`) in eclipse ADT. So i downloaded a normal java eclipse, and now i have the option. And it worked! Question is now can i add that feature to eclipse ADT? Thanks

Comment: @AlaaM. Don't know much about ADT, you can add the ADT plug-ins to a normal Eclipse install.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you check out the source code from its source control repository or download it as an archive file from its website and then import it into Eclipse, same as any other project.

Comment: I succeeded doing that, but seems like editing the `plugin.xml` file doesn't change the GUI.

Comment: Did you do Run As... Eclipse application? Changes to a plugin files don't affect the actual instance of Eclipse you are using to edit them, that would be too dangerous because it could crash. You have to run a separate Eclipse application using Run As.

Comment: When i click Run As i only get `Java Applet` and `Java Application` and they both give errors: `selection does not contain an applet` / `selection does not contain a main type`

Comment: You need to install [that thing for eclipse plugin development](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/)... basically go read the documentation.

Comment: if you have already installed it, it probably means you didn't check out the right _source code_ for the plugin. Or else some additional setup is required, which should be documented in the project.

Comment: Maybe it is because i'm using ADT?

Comment: no you probably didn't check out the right source code. Without more details it's difficult to know.

Comment: There's 2 possible source codes for the plugin and i tried them both: http://jdt-comments.appspot.com/ . One under the link `Source code`, and one under `Download for eclipse`.

Comment: did you miss my comment where I linked to the plugin you have to install?

Comment: it leads to a page of a lot of downloadable links: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/